# How can I get total number of seconds from a timestamp in Apache Drill

Tags: sql, timestamp, apache-drill

I'm trying to covert a timestamp to seconds in apache drill and can only find functions to extract the number of seconds in a timestamp instead rather than the timestamp converted to seconds.

I'm doing this to get the difference between dates to calculate the time between them.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to convert the date to UNIX_TIMESTAMP.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-05-29 08:18:53.0', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') FROM (VALUES(1));

 +-------------+
 |   EXPR$0    |
 +-------------+
 | 1432912733  |
 +-------------+
```

[Apache Drill UNIX_TIMESTAMP](https://drill.apache.org/docs/date-time-functions-and-arithmetic/#unix_timestamp)